# Jquery reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, referenceerror

Hey Guys i want to use jquery local because my app doesnt have access to the internet. When i use the jquery google source my code works but with my source local i get a reference error.

jquery-3.1.1.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):51 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

If you could help me i would be really thankful. I already tried to use the source without port or ip but that also didnt work.

Here is my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Socket.io</title>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.42.1:8080/home/pi/myNode/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Communicating with socket.io!</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Geschwindigkeit</td>
    <td>Neigung</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="geschwindigkeit" id="v"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Neigung" id="acc"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

 <p> </p>
 <table>
 <tr>
<td><input type="button" value="Move" id="move" /></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Enable" id="enable" /></td>
<td><input type="button" value="test" id="test" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="button" value="Stop" id="stop" /></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Ping" id="ping" /></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Disable" id="disable" /></td>
   </tr>
   </table>

    <script>
       var socket = io.connect();


        // A dialog box is displayed when the server sends us a "message"
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            alert('Nachricht: ' + message);
        })
 // When the button is clicked, a "message" is sent to the server
        $('#enable').click(function () {
            socket.emit('enable', 'disable');
        })

        $('#disable').click(function () {
            socket.emit('disable', 'disable');
        })

             $('#test').click(function () {
            socket.emit('message', 'test');
        })

        $('#move').click(function () {
              var geschw = document.getElementById("v").value;
      var neig = document.getElementById("acc").value;
      var cmd = new String( "m " + geschw + "    " + neig)
                  socket.emit('move', cmd);
        })

        $('#stop').click(function () {
            socket.emit('stop', 'Car stopped');
        })

        $('#ping').click(function () {
            socket.emit('poke', 'Hallo');
        })


    </script>
    <p></p>
    "<img src='http:192.168.178.51:8077/?action=stream' width='320' height='240'>
</body>
```

Comment: So yeah i changed my code to

              <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"  src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
but it still doesnt work i got the file in the folder js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to jQuery locally.

Download the file, then place it in the same directory as you index file. Or anywhere else, but link to it appropriately. E.g. libs/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js

Link to it like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Socket.io</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: If this helped you please click the green tick, so people know that this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're still trying to source your jquery from the remote CDN in that code you're showing, only socket.io is coming from local. Is that the issue? Make sure jquery is included in your project folder, then link it just like you're doing socket.io up there. If you're still having issues, send your folder structure and a screenshot of the error. 
You''ll get it!

Comment: I tried to get it from my pi not the online cdn. I just wanted to use the right Path.

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order of the libraries:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Socket.io</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.42.1:8080/home/pi/myNode/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
```